# Fragment with ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I already have a viewpager that works but I have a small bug. The user can add or delete the pages himself. In these pages I have an edittext (in fact I have more but it is the same case for all) which is the name of the page. If the user  creates a page that it calls "page 1", deletes it and creates another page immediately after it, which it calls "page 2", the fragment will display the data on page 1 ". Why ? I call `notifyDataSetChanged ();` After creating and deleting a page so why the fragment is not refreshed? If I leave the activity and I restart it the "page 2" that the user created will display the data of "page 2". What more do I need to do to properly refresh the fragment?

I use this library : [link](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout)

**My onCreate method**

```
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            viewPagerTab = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);
            pages = new FragmentPagerItems(this);
            int i = 0;
            for (Points points : Pref.getList_points()) {
                pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of(points.getName(), FragmentConfigurationPoints.class, new Bundler().putInt("param1", i).get()));
                i++;
            }

            adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), pages){
                @Override
                public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
                    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
                }
            };

            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

**My methods to add a page**

```
pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of(
        Pref.getList_points().get(Pref.get_size() - 1).getName(),
        FragmentConfigurationPoints.class,
        new Bundler().putInt("param1", Pref.get_size() - 1).get()
));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(Pref.get_size() - 1, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Reset adapter with new Data should force to load new data.

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

notifyDataSetChanged() won't properly do what you need. 
this method refresh data inside adapter not Adapter itself.
check out the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

```
void notifyDataSetChanged ()
/*Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.*/
```

Comment: If I replace `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` with
`adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager (), pages) {
 @Override
Public int getItemPosition (Object object) {
Return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
 }
};`


It does not change anything at all ...

Comment: @filol reset adapter! viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); i didn't mean to redefine it

Comment: Oh yes sorry, but I have already tried and it does not work better

Comment: @filol i had similar thing on my project with both listView and pageview and resetting adapter works fine.
check out your new data and first new data to adapter and then reset it. good luck